# jQuery Bootgrid using ADO.Net with SQL Server 2012

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, ado.net, jquery-bootgrid

I have read that jQuery Bootgrid is simple to use for sorting, paging and searching options and seen the demo's. Can anyone clarify me that can I use this jQuery Bootgrid for my C# ASP.Net application. I m using default GridView option binding with ADO.Net services.

I have read one article in this [link](http://phpflow.com/php/simple-example-bootgrid-server-side-with-php-mysql-and-ajax/), but it explained for php & MySQL. Is it applicable to use the same concept for ADO.Net.

Please some one throw some lights on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootgrid is a jQuery plugin, which can be populated with **json data**, or you can build html `table` by yourself (filling a `tbody` with `tr`'s and `td`'s).

Surely you can use it with a C# ASP.NET *WebApplication*, or *WebForms*, or anything which can receive a http request, but it won't work binding to an ADO.NET, SQL Server Connection out of the box, as do `GridView`, because a `GridView` is a **server-side** component which is compiled and *translated* to html by the server. So the client receives only the resulted html, whereas Bootgrid is **client-side**, which means you can make it work with any kind of server application by using ajax calls.

You should build an **API** to receive requests from bootgrid, for example, or fill the html table data manually, as I said. The table must have their structure, like this sample:

```
<table id="grid-data" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
            <th data-column-id="sender">Sender</th>
            <th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Received</th>
            <th data-column-id="link" data-formatter="link" data-sortable="false">Link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

In the sample above, they only configured the **table header** with column specifications, take note those data-column-id, data-type, data-anything attributes. They are bootgrid's common configurations.

In this example, we don't have a `tbody` with `tr`'s and `td`'s already populated, it's a sample to be loaded with json data.

Another option is to manually build rows with `td`'s:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>10238</td>
        <td>eduardo@pingpong.com</td>
        <td>14.10.2013</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>
```

...and bootgrid will work as well.

It's really simple to use bootgrid, just take a read in their [examples here](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples).